# I want to set hour in a date without change the day month and year

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set a default hour to an input date that has got day, month and year

in my html component I have this

```
(dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
```

that call my function.

In my dayClicked function I want to set to default the 9:00 AM hour without changing day ecc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What object is $event.day now ?

If it is Date object do something like this:

```
const x = new Date(event.value);
x.setHours(9, 0, 0);
return x;
```